# How to fix the strange character in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice, mathtype

I have a docx file with mathtype 6.8

The docx only has this equation.

[image]

But when I load in libreoffice 3.6.2.2, it becomes

[image]

Here is the doc file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqt9zjcat1fyv1p/%E6%B8%AC%E8%A9%A6libreoffice%E6%95%88%E6%9E%9C_v0.1.docx

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Since LO can't import MathType formulas directly, you will have to convert the formula to any other format. There are different MathType-to-XY-Coverterts, for example by [GrindEQ](http://grindeq.com/) (they offer an online converter, too).

Comment: Is there any whole word converter? GrindEQ seems only convert one formula once. Thank you~

Comment: AFAIK there's no such free software / shareware - as usual with proprietary software :-( . The only solution besides buying MathType or any other tool is to ask the guy who gave you the document to convert the formula to an open format.